# Laravel Undefined property: stdClass::$opprank

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am absolutely stumped by this issue, where I have tried numerous tests to determine the source of the problem. In my Controller, I assign a number of values to my `$players` array. When I remove the variable `opprank` everything works fine. When I have it included however, I get the **error** message

> *Undefined property: stdClass::$opprank*

I have tried dumping the values of `$players` where the opprank value is shown as expected. I have tried setting it to a static value of '10' as opposed to the DB value but receive the same error. Hopefully someone can spot where I am going wrong...

**SystemController.php**

```
            foreach ($teams as $team)
            {
                if ($players[$key]->team == $team->id)
                {
                    // Replace Team ID with Team Short Code for Display Purposes
                    $players[$key]->team = $team->code;

                    $matchups = DB::table('schedule')->where('week', $week->value)->get();

                    foreach ($matchups as $matchup)
                    {
                        if ($team->id == $matchup->home_team)
                        {
                            $opp = DB::table('teams')->select('code', 'rank')->where('id', $matchup->away_team)->first();

                            $players[$key]->opponent = $opp->code;
                            $players[$key]->opprank = $opp->rank;
                            $players[$key]->status = 'Home';
                        }
                        else if ($team->id == $matchup->away_team)
                        {
                            $opp = DB::table('teams')->select('code', 'rank')->where('id', $matchup->home_team)->first();

                            $players[$key]->opponent = $opp->code;
                            $players[$key]->opprank = $opp->rank;
                            $players[$key]->status = 'Away';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach ($positions as $position)
            {
                if ($players[$key]->position == $position->id)
                {
                    $players[$key]->position = $position->short_name;
                }
            }
        }

        return $players;
    }
}
```

**players.blade.php**

```
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dt-players-all">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Player</th>
                                <th>Team</th>
                                <th>Opponent</th>
                                <th>Game</th>
                                <th>Opp. Rank</th>
                                <th>FPPG</th>
                                <th>Salary</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            @foreach ($players as $player)

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$player->position}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$player->name}} <font color="red"><b>{{$player->injury_status}}</b></font></td>
                                    <td>{{$player->team}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$player->opponent}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$player->status}}</td>
                                    <td class="center">

                                        @if ($player->opprank <= 10)
                                            <font color="red"><b>{{$player->opprank}}</b></font>
                                        @elseif ($player->opprank > 10 && ($player->opprank <= 20))
                                            <b>{{$player->opprank}}</b>
                                        @else
                                            <b><font color="green">{{$player->opprank}}</font></b>
                                        @endif

                                    </td>
                                    <td class="center">{{$player->fppg}}</td>
                                    <td class="center">${{$player->salary}}</td>
                                </tr>

                            @endforeach

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: Please try this one as $players[$key][opprank] = $opp->rank; and all. try this one.

Comment: @Phil It says its line 49 in the players.blade.php but that is just the empty line above the if/elseif/else statement.

Comment: @BrettPowell in the controller, before return use Log::info($players) and check the output in the log info file. i.e., values are correct or not. We can trace by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise it to a NULL value or to some value you need just after you get `$key` - I think it should be inside some foreach() loop not visible in the question.

```
$players[$key]->opprank = NULL;
```

As I think you are getting this error because you set the value of `opprank` in some condition, which fails to assign if the condition is not executed. If it is just a warning, assign it in this way.

Also try adding in the else part (if this works - will be the best fix)

```
if () {
  // your code
}
else if () {
  // your code
}
else {
  $players[$key]->opprank = NULL;
}
```

At the last try you can obviously do an isset() or !empty() check for them. Only if your output is fine and you just want to get rid of warnings.

```
if(isset($player->opprank)) {
  // existing code for if, else if and else
}
```

Comment: Yes, because you are using if statements before you set opprank attribute, some of the players doesn't have it. You can also check the existence of the opprank attribute in your template, before using it.

Comment: add this line at else part.

Comment: after if... else if... else { set Null }

Comment: I just tried this but I am still encountering the same problem. As mentioned in my original post, I had also already tried setting the variable to a static value in case the issue was the value missing but it doesn't seem to be that.

Comment: @BrettPowell If your logic works fine and produces the required output, an isset or !empty should work. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I finally realized that one of my teams was screwed up due to importing from an outdated 2015 CSV. I will need to do work on error checking a bit better but problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($matchups as $matchup)
                {
                    if ($team->id == $matchup->home_team)
                    {
                        $opp = DB::table('teams')->select('code', 'rank')->where('id', $matchup->away_team)->first();

                        $players[$key]->opponent = $opp->code;
                        $players[$key]->opprank = $opp->rank;
                        $players[$key]->status = 'Home';
                    }
                    else if ($team->id == $matchup->away_team)
                    {
                        $opp = DB::table('teams')->select('code', 'rank')->where('id', $matchup->home_team)->first();

                        $players[$key]->opponent = $opp->code;
                        $players[$key]->opprank = $opp->rank;
                        $players[$key]->status = 'Away';
                    }
                     else{
                    $players[$key]->opprank = NULL;
                   }
                }
```

Comment: Just tried this but still getting the same error. As the error message is "Undefined Property", it seems that the issue is with the actual variable not being read as opposed to the value itself.

Comment: @BrettPowell use Log::info($players) before return from controller file.